# Why is my LastPasswordChangedDate 5 hours in the future?

Tags: configuration

I have a Sitecore 8.1-3 instance. I am trying to get the Datetime that the user's password was last changed.  I am using this code:

```
var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(myUserName);
var elapsedTimeSinceLastPasswordChange = DateTime.Now - membershipUser.LastPasswordChangedDate;
```

I am finding that `membershipUser.LastPasswordChangedDate` is always 5 hours ahead of the time on my machine.  I am running all of this on my local computer.  I am in the US Eastern time zone.  The time on my PC is correct.  And I have the following setting in my Sitecore.config file:

`<setting name="ServerTimeZone" value="Eastern Standard Time"/>`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in Eastern Standard Time then that means that you are 5 hours behind UTC. The `LastPsswordChangedDate` stored in the database is always in UTC to avoid issues with changing time-zones. This way, logic that views the stored value can be set to view it in the time-zone that you specified in the `ServerTimeZone` setting.

The general idea here is that the data should be separate from and thus should not depend on the business logic. Regardless of what you set as a display setting/preference/etc. the data should be consistent and standardized, so that the logic run on the data simply determines how it is to be presented.

#### Getting time in the `ServerTimeZone` using Sitecore's `DateUtil` methods

What you want to do is use Sitecore's `DateUtil` class to convert the resulting time to the server time that you specified. You are looking for the `Sitecore.DateUtil.ToServerTime(...)` method. Your `DateTime.Now` should be returned in the server time, but your `membershipUser.LastPasswordChangedDate` is still in UTC and must be converted, like so:

```
var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(myUserName);
var passwordChangedDate = Sitecore.DateUtil.ToServerTime(membershipUser.LastPasswordChangedDate);
var elapsedTimeSinceLastPasswordChange = DateTime.Now - passwordChangedDate;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  I didn't realize that I had to do anything to membershipUser.LastPasswordChangedDate.

Comment: No problem :) Yeah, `membershipUser.LastPasswordChangedDate` is an entity that comes with ASP.NET Membership, and Sitecore doesn't extend the base getter implementation with custom logic.