# How to get the our local date and time from the sitecore datetime field(raw value format - yyymmddThhmmssZ)?

Tags: sitecore-api

I have set the date in the sitecore item for some datetime field as below.

[image]

And its getting saved as below format in the master/web database.

**20170401T073000Z**

When I try to get that value using the below API.

```
webDB = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("web");
var item = webDB.GetItem(itemId);
var dateField = (DateField)item.Fields["fieldName"];
_xxx = Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime(dateField.Value).ToString();
```

I am getting the below date and time
4/1/2017  7:30:00 AM

Here the difference is 5.30 hrs.

How do I get the exact time which is showing the CMS?

Answer (score 12):

Sitecore stores its date/time values in `UTC`. And you are 5h30m ahead or behind UTC.

If you'd like to display DateTimes in `Server Time`:

```
webDB = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("web");
var item = webDB.GetItem(itemId);
var dateField = (DateField)item.Fields["fieldName"];
var serverTime = Sitecore.DateUtil.ToServerTime(dateField.DateTime);
_xxx = Sitecore.DateUtil.FormatShortDateTime(serverTime);
```

When using Sitecore's `ToServerTime` method, by default it will use the TimeZone configured in the Operating System. If you would like to override that, you can adjust the `ServerTimeZone` setting in Sitecore.config:

```
<setting name="ServerTimeZone" value="Eastern Standard Time"/>
```

References:

- https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/4011/73
- https://benrausch.net/sitecore-8-datefield-datetime-values-are-now-utc
- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/utc/datetime/datetime_types
- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/utc/datetime/datetime_best_practices

Answer (score 3):

The below code is also a solution for this issue:

```
var dateField = (DateField)item.Fields["fieldname"];
var isoDate = Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoDateToServerTimeIsoDate(dateField.Value);
```